# How long is a full day in Alto’s Adventure?

Tags: altos-adventure

One of the goals for level 38 in Alto’s Adventure is to survive a full day.

How long is a full day in real time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approximately 7 minutes 20 seconds. I watched [this video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=Dm-BgDgiGI0) of a walkthrough of the level and the start of the run was about 4:50 and they got the challenge completed at 12:10. Also [this video](http://youtu.be/F3uccCqByJQ) the run started at 0:20 and got the challenge at 7:40

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how long it is in real time, but I found it useful to pause the game every once in a while to check on my progress. The pause screen will tell you how close you are to each goal. After one full day, for example, it would say 50% for your goal.